# R Shiny: How do I unbold the column names and reduce the font size of the column names with renderTable

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

I have been using `renderTable` in R Shiny to display my table. I know how to use the CSS command to shrink the font size of my table by a certain percentage. However, how can I unbold *only* the column names and reduce the font size of *only* the column names?

We can start with this simple example provided [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/tableOutput.html). The first part of the code uses `renderTable` on the default dataset `iris`. How can I go about unbolding and shrinking the font size of the column names *only*?

Answer (score 2):

### Method

Using firefox, I brought up https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widgets.html (since your link wasn't a complete shiny app), and then went into the inspector (`Ctrl-Shift-I`), clicked on the "pick an element from the page" icon ([image: small icon]), and then clicked on a table header.

On the right of the inspector, I see the effective CSS under "Rules":

[image: firefox inspector right-bar]

In there, you can see

```
thead:first-child > tr:first-child > th {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Inside there, added the two fields, effectively making it:

```
thead:first-child > tr:first-child > th {
    border-top: 0;
    font-size: xx-small;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

and the column headers only shrink and un-bold.

### TL;DR

You can add the following to your `ui` element:

```
tags$style(HTML("
    thead:first-child > tr:first-child > th {
        border-top: 0;
        font-size: xx-small;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
"))
```